# Passing Lists as a QueryString - should I use JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, query-string

Lets say I've got an online dating site, users can filter the user list based on various criteria,  Height, Age, BodyType, Ethnic Origin....

I want to pass the criteria to the pager, via QueryString.  Height and Age are easy as these are ranges, and I would use

```
MinHeight=3&MaxHeight=12&MinAge=21&MaxAge=30
```

However other Criteria like BodyType and Ethnic orgins are Lists of ForeignKey values e.g:

```
Ethnitity:2,3,5
```

What is the best way to pass these as a QueryString?  Should I convert it to a Json string eg:

```
www.site.com?filterjson={\"minage\":0,\"maxage\":0,\"minheight\":0,\"maxheight\":0,\"bodytypelist\":[1,2,3],"ethnicitylist\":[2,3,4],\"eyecolorlist\":[],\"haircolorlist\":[],\"orientationlist\":[]}
```

Or is this not-valid/overkill/too complex?

Maybe something like this:

```
MinHeight=3&MaxHeight=12&bodytypes=1,2,3&
```

and parse the list values by splitting the ','?????

I don't know the ups and downs of all these ideas.  So how would you pass a list of values in a querystring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using comma-separated values is the most pragmatic approach in my opinion. You can use this code to split values:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["bodytypes"]))
{
   string[] rgs = Request.QueryString["bodytypes"].Split(new char[] { ',' });
}
```

Comment: I'm inclined to agree although commas turn into somethig like this www.site.com/search?bodytype=?=2%2C3%2C4 %2C representing a comma.  Doesn't look nice, but I guess that doesn't matter.  But I am a little concerned that comma is not a valid character in a querystring.  Not sure if this is a problem or not.

Comment: You can replace comma with dash (bodytype=1-2-3).

Answer (score 0):

Both will work, though querystring is much easier to be 'hacked'. However if you have it well protected from malicious/unexpected values, I say it's fine.

Consuming data via querystring is relatively more straightforward than from JSON.